# how can I search for cells which display E+ scientific notation?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find cells that show an E+

Is this possible with VBA?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: You can use the `.Find` method although that may be cumbersome.  `.Find("E+", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)`.  It will be easier to provide *good* assistance/recommendation if you can show us what you have tried, and describe what you're really trying to do. Do you need to just find a few cells? Or do you need to iterate over a great number of cells? What will you do to these cells once you find them? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub FindSci()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Value
        t = r.Text
        If IsNumeric(v) And InStr(1, t, "E") > 0 Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next r
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: OP may also consider checking the Range.NumberFormat property